# how to take input from one page and send them into another page in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm fairly new at this. I'm trying to build a report page in iframe according to user requirement user can create report with src, width and height ...and i successfully done this...i am able to create the report now i want this created report name will be show in the dropdown menu and when the user click on report name then user can see the report and the name of the report will add on dynamically in the dropdown....
i'm waiting for response ..here i'm going to share the code what i have done ...
i would say one more thing i don't want to add these data (Src,width ,height,name of the report) in the data base ...is that possible to create report and get the same report when i will click on the report name.
**index.html**

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">Reports</li>
        <li>
            <div class="buttons pull-right">
                <a href="{% url 'report:reporttest' %}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
            <a href="{% url 'report:reporttwo' %}">Report one</a>
        </li>
        {% for item in report_item %}
        <li>
            <a href="{% url 'report:add' %}">{{item.name}}</a>
        </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</li>
```

**reportform.html**

```
<form action = "add" method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form form-horizontal">  
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <strong>Add Report</strong>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover report-body attr-table">
                <tr>
                    <td>URL</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="src">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>WIDTH</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="width">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> HEIGHT</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="height">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td> NAME OF THE REPORT</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" name="name">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="submit">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**report_one.html**

```
<iframe src = {{src}} width= {{width}} height= {{height}} frameborder="0" allowfullscreen allowtransparency ></iframe>
```

**view.py **

```
def reportone(request):
    return render(request, 'report_one.html')
def reporttwo(request):
    return render(request, 'report_two.html')
def reporttest(request):
    return render(request, 'reportform.html')

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        report_item={}
        src=request.POST['src']
        width=request.POST['width']
        height=request.POST['height']
        name=request.POST['name']
        report_item={'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name}
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', report_item)
    else:
        return render(request, 'report_one.html' , report_item)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from extras.views import ObjectChangeLogView
from . import views

   app_name = 'report'

   urlpatterns = [
      path('reportone', views.reportone, name='reportone'),
      path('reporttwo', views.reporttwo, name='reporttwo'),
      path('reporttest', views.reporttest, name='reporttest'),
      path('add', views.add, name='add'),
    ]
```

Comment: please add your urls.py file for more understanding

Comment: @RiyasAc  done and  i have updated report dictionary also

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
class Report(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(null=False,max_length=300)
    width = models.IntegerField(default=300)
    height = models.IntegerField(default=200)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import Report
from django.db import models

class ReportForm(forms.Form):
    width = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':' form-control'}))
    height = forms.CharField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':' form-control'}))
    url = forms.URLField(max_length=300)
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)

    class Meta:
        model   = Report
        fields  = [ "url","width","height","name"]
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import ReportForm
from .models import Report

def reporttest(request):
    form = ReportForm()
    return render(request, 'reportform.html',{'form':form})

def add(request):
    report_item={}
    if request.method == "POST":
        obj= Report()
        obj.url =request.POST['url']
        obj.width=request.POST['width']
        obj.height=request.POST['height']
        obj.name=request.POST['name']
        obj.save()
        report_item={'src':request.POST['url'], 'width':request.POST['width'], 'height':request.POST['height'], 'name':request.POST['name']}
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', report_item)
    else:
        return render(request, 'report_one.html' , report_item)
```

**reportform.html**

```
<form action = "add" method= "post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form form-horizontal">  
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>Add Report</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-hover report-body attr-table">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{field.label}}</td>
                <td>{{field}}</td>
            </tr>  
            {% endfor %}
        </table>
        <input type="submit" >
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

**report_one.html**

```
<iframe width="{{width}}" height="{{height}}" src="{{src}}" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

please try this.After change model then migrate it.
simple url for checking :https://www.youtube.com/embed/F5mRW0jo-U4
[image]

Comment: not working ...i'm not having the report name in dropdown

Comment: index.html not used in views ?? Are you forgot add any view  in views.py ??

Comment: if i done some changed in the index.html like {{ name }} without for loop then i' m able to see the report name but when i click the name this will not show the created report i found page not found error and after click the report name in dropdown the name of the report name is also remove ...i want all the create report name in the dropdown

Comment: please save created details in new table and filter report name for dropdown

Comment: Are you need `reporttest` url to add report and `add` url to view saved data ??

Comment: yes .....inside the reporttest method i called reportform.html for create the report and inside the reportform.html the form action will call the add method for report save and to create the report.

Comment: Are you need show created reports in all time ??? then save in table

Comment: Are you need only display only when user is post  a report ?? then no need database

Comment: where is index.html is used ?? Is used for view created reports details  ??

Comment: index.html inside the template -inc and yes this is used for showing the dropdown . i meant it contain the main master page

Comment: which template include `index.html` file ??

Comment: main project  folder

Comment: Are you expecting saved report name display like dropdown options ??

Comment: do i need to migrate the report app ??? because i mentioned above i don't want to add the data inside the database because i don't have access

Comment: which you provide the code i think i need to save all the data in the data base but i'm not able to migrate this app.

Comment: what is your app name ?? i provide this code for migrate
`python manage.py makemigrations app_name` --> for makemigrations
`python manage.py migrate app_name` -->for migrate

Comment: Why not access DB ?? Are you working on local  Database ?? or other ??

Comment: i'm working on the DB but not able to migrate the app