# how to pass data in dictionary in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I want to pass the data from dictionary

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        src=request.POST['src']
        width=int(request.POST['width'])
        height=int(request.POST['height'])
        name=request.POST['name']
        report_name ={'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name}
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', {'report_name':report_name})
    else:
        pass
```

In above code if i pass whole dictionary like below

```
return render(request, 'report_one.html', {'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name})
```

this works and display the required page but if I pass report_name
like below

```
return render(request, 'report_one.html'{'report_name':report_name})
```

this doesn't work.

So my question is how to pass the dictionary from view to html templates in case of the data is taken by the other page ?

Answer (score 0):

You written `return render(request, 'report_one.html', {'report_name':report_name})` from this `report_name` is already a `dict` why should pass another dict. I would suggest for do something like this. please try this.

```
def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        report_name = {}
        src=request.POST['src']
        width=int(request.POST['width'])
        height=int(request.POST['height'])
        name=request.POST['name']
        report_name ={'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name}
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', report_name)
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: i want to acees the report name in my index html file and for this i have used {% if report_name%}
                        {% for item in report_name %}
                        <li {% if not perms.secrets.view_secret %} class="disabled"{% endif %}>
                            <a href="{% url 'report:add' %}">{{ item.name }}</a>
                        
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
                        {% endif %}

Comment: could you please see this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/63551372/13755750