# In Django for loop in html template is not working correctly

Tags: django

[image]i want the report name in the dropdown menu but i'm not able to fetch the items from dictionary
**views.py**

```
def add(request):
    report_item = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        src=request.POST['src']
        width=request.POST['width']
        height=request.POST['height']
        name=request.POST['name']
        report_item = {'src':src, 'width':width, 'height':height, 'name':name}
        #template = loader.get_template('report_one.html')
        #context={'report_item':report_item}
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', report_item)
    else:
        return render(request, 'report_one.html', report_item)
```

**index.html**

```
li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Reports<span class="caret"></span></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li class="dropdown-header">Reports</li>
    <li>
        <div class="buttons pull-right">
            <a href="{% url 'report:reporttest' %}" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" title="Add"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <a href="{% url 'report:reporttwo' %}">Report one</a>
    </li>
    {% for key, value in report_item.items %}
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'report:add' %}">{{ value.name }}</a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

i want to add the report name dynamically in the dropdown menu

i have successfully created the report and the reportname also display in the dropdown but the problem is that when i click on the report name the reportname will removed from the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would try:

```html
<li>
    <a href="{% url 'report:add' %}">{{ name }}</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, just call the key of the dict ass follow: **{{ name }}**

Comment: i have already used this {{ name }} code ...but i'm getting the issue ...when i click this report name in the dropdown the name of the report will remove from the dropdown ...i want all the report name will show in the dropdown menu

Comment: can you provide expected output you want in your template?

Comment: each report is hold on a model?

Answer (score 0):

Your context data passed to the template doesn't contain a value named `report_item`, so you're effectively looping through a falsey value. It doesn't raise an error in Django's template language to try and loop through `None` - it just does nothing.

What you want to do is un-comment `#context={'report_item':report_item}` and pass that to `render` instead of `report_item`.

Here's how I would refactor your view:

```py
def add(request):
    report_item = {}

    if request.method == "POST":
        report_item.update(
            height=request.POST["height"],
            name=request.POST["name"],
            src=request.POST["src"],
            width=request.POST["width"],
        )

    context = {"report_item": report_item}
    return render(request, "report_one.html", context)
```

Comment: same problem not getting data src width height have blank value

Comment: It will only have value on a POST request. if you're just using a GET request it will still be a blank value. Have you doubled checked that?

Comment: could you please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/q/63551372/13755750    actually i want this whol thing on my project but as of now i'm not getting any solution